# Call C++ code from Python, which in turn calls Python again (i.e. Python->C++->Python), is this possible?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I have a multithreaded C++ library that currently already has the ability of calling Python scripts from the inside via the Python C API.
However, I would like to also add an outside Python wrapper to this C++ library to be able to use it as a module, once again with the C API.

Is it possible to do this Python->C->Python chain, or will things like the GIL create issues for this?

Comment: Check last paragraph [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#thin-ice).

Comment: Calling C from Python is relatively easy with `ctypes`. For calling C++ you will probably need something like [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11).